# error APT2008: attribute 'android:name' in <service> tag must be a valid Java class name

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have an android app I'm building with Xamarin, it compiled fine before I renamed, the solution, project, and package, but now I have the following compilation error:

```
error APT2008: attribute 'android:name' in <service> tag must be a valid Java class name.
```

The error line is in the manifest generated in the debug folder:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ActiviteService" />
<service android:name="com.my-domain.sub.android.activiteservice" android:exported="false" android:directBootAware="true" />
<receiver android:name="crc6426b0443894528d3f.BlockCalls">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my manifest:

```
<application android:label="Link" android:icon="@drawable/logo">
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ActiviteService" />
    <service android:name="com.my-domain.sub.android.activiteservice" android:exported="false" android:directBootAware="true" />
</application>
```

And the corresponding class:

```
namespace Sub.Droid
{
    [Service (Name = "com.my-domain.sub.android.activiteservice")]
    class ActiviteService : Service
    {
...
```

I cleaned the project, deleted the debug and obj folders, rebuilt but the error remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the hyphen in the name (my-domain). Removing it alowed compilation.